# Task doesn't stop

Tags: c#, task

I created a new task. I'm uisng a while inside. I want to somehow to stop it.

```
 Task task;
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    private  void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        task  = Task.Factory.StartNew(Run2, cts.Token);


    }
    void Run2()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {

            i++;
            Write(Convert.ToString(i));
           // textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    public void Write(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(Write), new object[] { value });
          //  return;
        }
        textBox1.Text = value;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            cts.Cancel();

    }
}
```

When i'm using cancel button my task doesn't stop. My TextBox is still increasing.

Comment: `StartNew(Action, CTS)` will only prevent it from starting if the CTS was canceled. Try to check the CTS every now and then yourself in the loop. Also try to use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep

Comment: The task won't be killed, you will need to explicitly check for the cancellation token being cancelled inside the loop in `Run2`. The only purpose the cancellation token has in your `StartNew` call is that the task will not be spun up if it has already been cancelled, but after it has started, you do nothing to stop it.

Comment: You should check iscancelatinonrequested like:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: If you want to report progress use `IProgress<T>`, not `Invoke`. Don't use `Thread.Sleep` either, that just wastes a thread. Change your method's signature to `async Task` and use `await Task.Delay(1000)` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: Check Stephen Toub's article: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: Can i use task and changing values in ui thread without to using invoke?